# in html and css how to get the box space to be smaller?

Tags: html, css

ok so when you go on a mobile screen how do you get the boxes to close the gap and like, stack and stuff? thank you i am new to coding. the gap is fine full screen but when it gets smaller it is weird. any suggestions?

```
      top: 23%;
      left: 30%;
      color: white;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 4.6vw;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    p {
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      top: -1px;
      left: 15px;
      height: 25px;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    ul {
      word-spacing: .2em;
      letter-spacing: .2em;
    }
    ul li {
      font-family: Arial;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 40px;
      top: 43%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 250px;
      margin-left: 115px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      word-spacing: normal;
      background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
      border: 2px solid white;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 90%;
      width: 150px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    ul li:link,
    ul li:visited {
      font-family: Arial;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 250px;
      margin-left: 115px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      word-spacing: normal;
      background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
      border: 2px solid white;
      font-size: 90%;
      width: 150px;
      height: 40px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    li {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    ul li:hover,
    ul li:active {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul li a:hover, ul li a:active {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }  

    ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Metro-M.svg/2000px-Metro-M.svg.png">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="m.css">
<title>morgan</title>

</head>
<body>
<center><h1>A Girl With A Passion</h1></center>
<ul>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="life" ><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="prot"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="resume"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="me"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the @media command to have a custom style for specific screen sizes

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){Your css here}
```

Comment: so how would i do that?

Comment: Use the dev tools in your browser to find out when everything starts to get messed up and change the 480px to whatever width that is. Then, when the device width is equal to or less than that size, the css inside that block will work